# ¿Es correcto este codigo para declarar un indice tipo clustered (agrupado) en SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, ssms

> En base a la siguiente tabla de Ordenes (tblOrders)

```
CREATE TABLE tblOrders
(
    OrderID INT NOT NULL,
    Fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
    productID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cantidad INT NOT NULL,
    precioTotal INT NOT NULL,
    Descripcion VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

SELECT * FROM tblOrders
```

> 1. Realizar un índice agrupado, en donde declares el nombre del índice, 
>      el tipo de índice y el campo por el cual se basa el índice. 
>      Se desea que el campo OrderID reestructura físicamente la tabla.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_IndiceAgrupado_OrderID
    ON dbo.tblOrders (OrderID);
GO

SELECT * FROM tblOrders
```

(Se los agradezco mucho).

Answer (score 2):

Es correcto.

La manera más fácil de averiguarlo, es utilizar el management studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El enunciado dice: Nombre del índice (Ok)

Tipo de índice (Ok)

Columna OrderId (Ok)

Reestructura físicamente la tabla.

> Una tabla o una vista puede contener los siguientes tipos de índices:
>   Clúster Los índices clúster ordenan y almacenan las filas de los datos
>   de la tabla o vista de acuerdo con los valores de la clave del índice.
>   Son columnas incluidas en la definición del índice. Solo puede haber
>   un índice clúster por cada tabla, porque las filas de datos solo
>   pueden estar almacenadas de una forma.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15

En ningún momento se pide que exista una restricción primary key, por tanto tú solución es adecuada.